# Turning on a PC with a Orange Pi

Tags: power, remote-control

I have been working on a system which allows to turn on a PC without physical presence. I'm using an Orange Pi platform with a board designed for testing the embedded systems.

My assumption:

- green cable from the ATX power supply is connected through the relay to the mo-bo
- power-on button cables are connected to the circuit which acts like an open-collector.

How do I want this circuit to work:

- I turn on a relay (green cable is shorted directly to the mother-board)
- After 1 second I enable for a moment an open-collector circuit.
- If it comes to shutdown, I turn off the relay

Is it gonna work? Remote working is what I want to gain. Orange Pi is connected to the network and I operate it using SSH.

Comment: Are you aware of the wake-on-lan standard? You could use that and skip the pi entirely.

Comment: Of course, I know about wake-on-lan but I cannot use it. It's too expensive solution from this point of view. Orange Pi is an essential element of this process. I want to use it both for powering-on the computer and programming via SPI.

Comment: @Hearth PC is not even connected to a network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relay is unnecessary. Let the PC motherboard manage the power-on signal to the power supply. If you just open the relay to power down, you'll "crash" the PC, and it will require more time to boot up next time, possibly requiring manual intervention.

Your OrangePi just needs to pulse the power-on button signal to the motherboard to power-up or power-down the PC. You can monitor the main 5V output of the power supply to determine which state it is in at any given moment. When you power down this way, the PC operating system will shut down in an orderly fashion and then shut off the power supply.